# Do you need to give the source when making a "Privatkopie" (Germany)?

Tags: copyright, licensing, germany

In Germany, when making a Privatkopie, for example by taking notes in digital form, do you need to include from which book the notes were taken, the author's name, ... if you are only going to privately use your digital notes?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, § 63 (1) 1 UrhG, the obligation to attribute the source, concerns only exceptions listed there.
The applicable exception of § 53 UrhG, copies for private use, is not listed in § 63.